# Dropdown value stays selected

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown and I want the input selected after the page refresh or post. So every post has the same `$hoogte_array`.

```
    <table><form action="index.php" method="post">
    <tr><th>Hoogte: <select name="hoogte">
        <?
        $hoogte_array[1]= 63;  
        $hoogte_array[2]= 103;  
        $hoogte_array[3]= 123;  
        $hoogte_array[4]= 153;  
        $hoogte_array[5]= 173; 
        $hoogte_array[6]= 203;

        $kleur_array[1] = "groen";
        $kleur_array[2] = "blauw";

        foreach ($hoogte_array as $key => $valuehoogte) 
            {
            echo "<option value='".$key."''>".$valuehoogte."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select></th>

    <th>Kleur: <select name="kleur">
        <?
        foreach ($kleur_array as $key => $valuekleur)
            {
            echo "<option value='".$key."''>".$valuekleur." </option>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please save the select selected value in session so you can use it after page reload or page redirect.

Comment: Well, when it changes, do you save it server side anywhere? You need to involve some type of saving process somewhere (Whether it be client side in javascript, or server side after submitting some type of form, or ajax call).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show selected value in select after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147229/show-selected-value-in-select-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($hoogte_array as $key => $valuehoogte) 
        {
          $hoogte = (isset($_POST['hoogte']))?$_POST['hoogte']:"1";
          $sel = ($hoogte == $key)? 'selected="selected"' : '';
          echo "<option value='".$key."'' ".$sel.">".$valuehoogte."</option>";
        }
```